# Caught: java.lang.StackOverflowError JsonBuilder closure

Tags: groovy, closures, jsonbuilder

I've been trying to read an xml file and convert it to json using groovy's JsonBuilder.  The problem is that when I print with

```
def builder = new JsonBuilder(jsonObject)
println builder.toPrettyString()
```

I got a Caught: `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Here is the whole stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:259)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeIterator(JsonOutput.java:442)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:272)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeIterator(JsonOutput.java:442)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:272)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeIterator(JsonOutput.java:442)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:272)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeIterator(JsonOutput.java:442)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:272)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeIterator(JsonOutput.java:442)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:272)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeIterator(JsonOutput.java:442)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:272)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeIterator(JsonOutput.java:442)
```

Here the code.

```
package firstgroovyproject

import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

class XmlToJsonII {
    static void main(def args){

        def carRecords = '''

<records>
    <car name='HSV Maloo' make='Holden' year='2006'>
        <countries>
            <country>
                Austria
            </country>
            <country>
                Spain
            </country>
        </countries>
        <record type='speed'>Production Pickup Truck with speed of 271kph
        </record>
    </car>
    <car name='P50' make='Peel' year='1962'>
        <countries>
            <country>
                Monaco
            </country>
        </countries>
        <record type='size'>Smallest Street-Legal Car at 99cm wide and 59 kg
            in weight</record>
    </car>
    <car name='Royale' make='Bugatti' year='1931'>
        <record type='price'>Most Valuable Car at $15 million</record>
        <countries>
            <country>
                Italia
            </country>
        </countries>
    </car>
<car name='Seat' make='Ibiza' year='1985'>
        <record type='price'>barato</record>
        <countries>
            <country>
                Spain
            </country>
        </countries>
    </car>
</records>
  '''


        def xmlRecords = new XmlSlurper().parseText(carRecords)

        def jsonObject = [:]
        jsonObject.records = []
        def records = jsonObject.records



        xmlRecords.car.each {xmlCar ->  
            records.add([
                countries:
                xmlCar.countries.children().each{ country ->
                        println   "country : ${country.text()}"
                        [country:   country.text()]
                },

                ])
        }

        def builder = new JsonBuilder(jsonObject)

        println builder.toPrettyString()
        //println builder.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: show us the whole stacktrace of the error and the jsonObject.  most likely there is an self-reference in there causing an infinite loop.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:259)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeIterator(JsonOutput.java:442)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:272)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeIterator(JsonOutput.java:442)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Your second (inner) `each` should be a `collect` instead.

**The real answer:** The return value of `each` is the original `Iterable` that invoked it. In this case that would be the XML object collection defined by the expression `xmlCar.countries.children()`. Since the objects in that collection contain references back to their own parents your JSON build causes an infinite regress that results in a stack overflow.

This doesn't happen with your first (outer) use of `each`, because you are not using the return value. Instead you are adding to a preexisting list (`records`).

By changing the second (inner) `each` into a `collect`, you are still iterating through the children of the `countries` elements. However, instead of returning the original XML children (the result of `each`) you are compiling and returning a list of maps of the form `[country:"country_string_from_xml"]`, which seems to be the desired behavior.

Confusing `each` and `collect` is a common rookie mistake in Groovy... which only made it all the more galling when it happened to ME last week. :-)